# cdnBasePath Modern Webpart - Private Office 365 CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, cdn

How should the the cndBasePath be in the write-manifest.json file if I want to use Private Office 365 CDN?

```
{
  "cdnBasePath": "mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/CDN/cdnlibrary/"
  //"cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->"
}
```

Also, in the package solution the `includeClientSideAssets` should be set to `true` or `false`?

I've been following the instructions from [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/hosting-extension-from-office365-cdn) which shows for a Public O365 CDN. Is there a major configuration difference between Public/Private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy the SPFx web part, below are the most commonly followed deployment approaches

**1.Azure CDN**

**2.Office 365 Public CDN**

**3.SharePoint Library in your tenant**

I think you want to select the second one, you need configure CDN in Office 365 Tenant and setup New Office 365 CDN in Tenant, then open **package-solution.json** file from config folder and set **includeClientSideAssets** value as **false**.The client side assets will not be packaged inside the final package (sppkg file) because these will be hosted on external Office 365 public CDN.

And open **write-manifests.json** from config folder, and update CDN base path as Office 365 CDN end point.

```
https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/[tenant]/sites/[site-collection-name]/[document-library]/[folder]
```

Refer to: [SharePoint Framework - Deploy SPFx WebParts To Office 365 Public CDN](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-office-365-public-cdn/)

Comment: I wanted it to be on a Office 365 Private CDN. Is it not possible at all?

Comment: You cannot deploy SPFx solutions using private CDN at least currently. If you still would like to get them hosted from fully secured URL, you'd use simply directly for example library in SharePoint without any CDN capabilities and you'd update the manifest URLs to point to that one. Check here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/How-do-we-deploy-SPFx-Web-Parts-to-a-Private-CDN-on-O365/m-p/69362